# Programming bootloader of a PIC microcontroller

Tags: pic, bootloader, microchip

I got a old used picdem board for free from my friend and I have a bootloader to it. It's old one got erased.

I don't have [ICD](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en537580&redirects=icd3) to program the bootloader, is there any way I can program the bootloader using usb or develop something by my own? But the problem is since the bootloader got erased by accident the usb won't be detected when plugged in.

I'm using PIC18F4550 microcontroller

Comment: Which PIC microcontroller you are going to program?

Comment: Sorry about that, it is "PIC18F4550" and the board is "http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en021940"

Comment: You can program this microcontroller by any other programmator, even self-made. First try to google give me [this](http://www.edaboard.com/thread42418.html)

Comment: they aren't that expensive, consider this one http://www.piccircuit.com/shop/7-pic-programmer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't program the bootloader over USB, because the bootloader contains the USB code. A blank PIC does not understand USB. It is not even running it's oscillator. Get an [iCP01](http://www.piccircuit.com/shop/pic-programmer/25-icp01-usb-pic-programmer.html) or an [ICD](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en537580).